# Как в цикле записывать в ячейки?

Tags: c#, excel

Я пытаюсь в цикле записать в разные ячейки, как работа с массивом в цикле, только Excel. Но записывается только 1 раз, хотя цикл идет.

```c#
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
 string file = @"C:\Users\Альфа\Desktop\Св.xls";

    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("Первый Лист");
    worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = new Cell(name);
    worksheet.Cells[i, 2] = new Cell(name_c);
    worksheet.Cells[i, 3] = new Cell(value);
    workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
    workbook.Save(file);
}
```

По разному пробовал, не записывается никак множество значений. Мне кажется, я не те методы использую. Подскажите, какие всё таки нужно?

Comment: вы на каждой итерации создаете `Workbook` и пишете его в один и тот же файл. То есть вот у вас 10 итераций - вы 10 раз записываете в один и тот же файл `Workbook` с одним листом.

Comment: Как я могу открывать тогда, а не создавать?

Comment: Как насчет вынести это `Workbook workbook = new Workbook();` до цикла, а это `workbook.Save(file);`, после цикла?

Comment: Вынес перед циклом `Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("Первый Лист");` и после цикла `workbook.Save(file);` Помогла, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы на каждой итерации создаете `Workbook` и пишете его в один и тот же файл. То есть, вот у вас 10 итераций - вы 10 раз записываете в один и тот же файл `Workbook` с одним листом.

Попробуйте так:

```csharp
string file = @"C:\Users\Альфа\Desktop\Св.xls";
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("Первый Лист");

for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{ 
    worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = new Cell(name);
    worksheet.Cells[i, 2] = new Cell(name_c);
    worksheet.Cells[i, 3] = new Cell(value);    
}

workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
workbook.Save(file);
```